# How do I refresh Activity like it is being loaded for first time?

Tags: android

I am trying to figure out how, when a user lands on my activity screen, it is "reloaded" as if it were being loaded for the first time.

I don't want my user hitting the back arrow and coming back to my activity with old information.

As it is now, when a user "comes back" to my page, the database list isn't being repopulated, and information they typed into EditText fields remains there.

I want the page, everytime the user comes to it, to be like it's their first time there.

Comment: do everything in onResume what you did in onCreate

Comment: I found a reasonable solution. I placed a finish() call everytime I left the current activity screen, either through a button click or clicking a listitem to go to another activity... any action that caused them to leave the current activity.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried using `recreate()` in your current activity? Try using it after your new values are populated.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just put everything that's in the onCreate() on the onResume. A bit ugly but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree with Kartik on this, as I understand, `android:noHistory='true'` will remove activity from application stack. So when user hits back, user will not be able to see the activity at all.

About activity not retaining its value, I would not recommend you this, as user expects that all values would be retained when back is hit, unless there is some specific requirement that you are trying to meet.

So I guess solution to your problem is, as others have suggested do your initialization on views in `onResume()`. But just doing this may not be sufficient, as views like `EditText` will by default cache the values anyways. So you might have to manually clear those in your on `onResume()`. Will keep looking to find any 'perfect' solution if any to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had solving similar problem like yours and I solve it whit lunch mode.
I think the best is to take a look of [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) set the lunch mode in single instance and then
in you onCreate and onResume you can code to refresh you view just the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

copy requred code into onResume() from onCreate() method